# unable to execute script to check driver availabiltiy and update based on laptop model

Tags: powershell

I have written one script to check driver availability and update then run accordingly based on laptop modal but script is not executing successful when i combine two modals.I am able to run this script separately. is there anything wrong with this script ? How can i execute below script ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

````
$Model = (Get-WmiObject -Class:Win32_ComputerSystem).Model
#Write-Output $Model
If ($Model = "Latitude 3400") {
$currentuser = ((gwmi win32_computersystem).username).split('\')[1]
$a =  Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_DisplayControllerConfiguration | Select-Object -Property Name
If ( $a -eq $null ) {
Write-Output "device is not installed"
Start-Sleep -s 5
Write-Output "installing device now"
Start-Sleep -s 5 
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\$currentuser\Downloads\Intel-HD-Graphics-Driver_P26YY_WIN_26.20.100.8141_A04.EXE" -ArgumentList '/s' -Wait -NoNewWindow
}

elseif ( $a -ne $null ) {
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver | 
    Where-Object {$_.devicename -eq 'Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620'} |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ([Version]$_.Driverversion -ge [Version]'26.20.100.8141') {  
            Write-Output "Version is Current"
           
        } 
        else {
            Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\$currentuser\Downloads\Intel-HD-Graphics-Driver_P26YY_WIN_26.20.100.8141_A04.EXE" -ArgumentList '/s' -Wait -NoNewWindow
        }
    }
    }
    

    elseif ($Model = "HP EliteBook 745 G6") {
    $currentuser = ((gwmi win32_computersystem).username).split('\')[1]
$b =  Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_DisplayControllerConfiguration | Select-Object -Property Name
If ( $b -eq $null ) {
Write-Output "device is not installed"
Start-Sleep -s 5
Write-Output "installing device now"
Start-Sleep -s 5 
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\$currentuser\Downloads\sp107554" -ArgumentList '/s' -Wait -NoNewWindow
}
elseif ( $b -ne $null ) {

Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver | 
    Where-Object {$_.devicename -eq 'AMD Radeon(TM) Vega 8 Graphics'} |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ([Version]$_.Driverversion -ge [Version]'27.20.1023.6005') {  
            Write-Output "Version is Current"
      
       } 
        else {
            Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\$currentuser\Downloads\sp107554" -ArgumentList '/s' -Wait -NoNewWindow
        }
    }
  }  
  }
  }
    ```
````

Comment: I've used devon from the sdk for things like this in the past, like this video driver that used to bluescreen for years:  `devcon update Graphics\igdlh64.inf "PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1912&SUBSYS_805E103C"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would do something more generic here by making use of an array of maintainable Hashtables in which the properties to check and also the path to the correct installer executable can be found.

```
$thisSystem       = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem
$model            = $thisSystem.Model
$currentUser      = $thisSystem.UserName.Split('\')[-1]
$controllerConfig = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_DisplayControllerConfiguration

# create a template path string. placeholder {0} gets its value below
$driverPath = "C:\Users\$currentUser\Downloads\{0}"

# build an array of hashtables for each model and the driver file that should be executed
$drivers = @{Model   = 'Latitude 3400'
             Path    = ($driverPath -f 'Intel-HD-Graphics-Driver_P26YY_WIN_26.20.100.8141_A04.EXE')
             Device  = 'Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620'
             Version = [Version]'26.20.100.8141'
           },
           @{Model   = 'HP EliteBook 745 G6'
             Path    = ($driverPath -f 'sp107554.exe')
             Device  = 'AMD Radeon(TM) Vega 8 Graphics'
             Version = [Version]'27.20.1023.6005'
           }

# select the appropriate driver for this model from the hashtable
$driver = $drivers | Where-Object {$_.Model -eq $model}

if ($driver) {
    Write-Host "Checking driver for $model"

    $install = $false
    if (!$controllerConfig) { 
        Write-Host 'Device is not installed'
        $install = $true 
    }
    else {
        $install = $true
        $versions = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PnPSignedDriver |  Where-Object {$_.Devicename -eq $driver.Device}
        foreach ($v in $versions) {
            if ([Version]$v.Driverversion -ge $driver.Version) {  
                Write-Host "Version is current or newer"
                $install = $false
                break
            } 
        }
    }
    if ($install) {
        Write-Host 'Installing device now'
        Start-Process -FilePath $driver.Path -ArgumentList '/s' -Wait -NoNewWindow
    }
}
else {
    Write-Warning "Model $model not found in the drivers array.."
}
```

Comment: Theo@, Thanks  much let me try it.

Comment: Theo@ i tested this script on dell latitude 3400 by uninstalling audio device it only shows" device is not installed" but not installing driver. But when i installed older audio version it worked fine. Anything we are missing in script?

Comment: Theo@ I managed to correct the code and it's working fine now for both cases. Thank you so much for your guidance and support.

Comment: Theo@Please check this POST https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64990346/failing-to-install-audio-driver-script-using-microsoft-update-as-source-on-dell   and suggest if anything wrong in code. I really appreciate for all your guidelines and help.