# Failing to install audio driver script using microsoft update as source on dell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run below code to install realtek audio driver on dell laptop but getting below error. Is it possible to use this script for all model laptop to install missing audio driver or update it? Any help would be greatly appreciated

**ERROR:**

````
RegistrationState ServiceID                            IsPendingRegistrationWithAU Service           
----------------- ---------                            --------------------------- -------           
                3 7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d                       False System.__ComObject
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80240024
+ $Downloader.Download()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
 
Installing Drivers...
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80240024
+ $InstallationResult = $Installer.Install()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException


 
**CODE:** 

$UpdateSvc = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.ServiceManager            
$UpdateSvc.AddService2("7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d",7,"")     

$Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session           
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher() 

$Searcher.ServiceID = '7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d'
$Searcher.SearchScope =  1 # MachineOnly
$Searcher.ServerSelection = 3 # Third Party
          
$Criteria = "IsInstalled=0 and Type='Driver'"
Write-Host('Searching Driver-Updates...') -Fore Green     
$SearchResult = $Searcher.Search($Criteria)          
$Updates = $SearchResult.Updates | Where-Object { $_.DriverManufacturer -like 'Realtek' }
    
#Show available Drivers...

$Updates | select Title, DriverModel, DriverVerDate, Driverclass, DriverManufacturer | fl

#Download the Drivers from Microsoft

$UpdatesToDownload = New-Object -Com Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl
$updates | % { $UpdatesToDownload.Add($_) | out-null }
Write-Host('Downloading Drivers...')  -Fore Green  
$UpdateSession = New-Object -Com Microsoft.Update.Session
$Downloader = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader()
$Downloader.Updates = $UpdatesToDownload
$Downloader.Download()

#Check if the Drivers are all downloaded and trigger the Installation

$UpdatesToInstall = New-Object -Com Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl
$updates | % { if($_.IsDownloaded) { $UpdatesToInstall.Add($_) | out-null } }

Write-Host('Installing Drivers...')  -Fore Green  
$Installer = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()
$Installer.Updates = $UpdatesToInstall
$InstallationResult = $Installer.Install()
if($InstallationResult.RebootRequired) {  
Write-Host('Reboot required! please reboot now..') -Fore Red  
} else { Write-Host('Done..') -Fore Green }  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I would change in your code.
For one thing, I think you are (unnecessarily) creating a new `Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl` object twice. Then you are not checking if there actually are updates to install, at which point the code should exit.

The test for the driver manufacturer in your code is `-like 'Realtek'`, but without wildcard characters (`*`) surrounding it, this is the same as `-eq 'Realtek'` and because of that you might miss a couple.

```
# check if the Windows Update service is running
if ((Get-Service -Name wuauserv).Status -ne "Running") { 
    Set-Service -Name wuauserv -StartupType Automatic
    Start-Service -Name wuauserv 
} 
# check if there are updates available
$UpdateSession  = New-Object -Com Microsoft.Update.Session
$UpdateSearcher = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
Write-Host 'Searching Driver-Updates...' -ForegroundColor Green     
$SearchResult   = $UpdateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Driver' and IsHidden=0")

# collect the updates
$UpdateCollection = New-Object -Com Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl
$Updates = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $SearchResult.Updates.Count; $i++) {
    $Update = $SearchResult.Updates.Item($i)
    # we are only interested in RealTek Audio driver updates
    # if you need to add more manufacturers, change the first part in the 'if' to for instance
    # $Update.DriverManufacturer -match 'Realtek|Conexant|Intel'
    if ($Update.DriverManufacturer -like '*Realtek*' -and
       ($Update.Title -like '*audio*' -or $Update.Description -like '*audio*')) {
        if (-not $Update.EulaAccepted) { $Update.AcceptEula() | Out-Null }
        [void]$UpdateCollection.Add($Update)
        # output a PsCustomObject for display purposes only
        $Update | Select-Object Title, DriverModel, DriverVerDate, Driverclass, DriverManufacturer
    }
}

# no updates found; exit the script
if ($null -eq $Updates -or $Updates.Count -eq 0) {
     Write-Host 'No Driver-Updates available...' -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
else {
    # Show available driver updates...
    $Updates | Format-List
   
    # download the updates
    Write-Host 'Downloading driver updates...' -ForegroundColor Green  
    $Downloader = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader()
    $Downloader.Updates = $UpdateCollection
    $Downloader.Priority = 3  # high
    [void]$Downloader.Download()

    # install the updates
    Write-Host 'Installing Drivers...' -ForegroundColor Green
    $Installer = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()
    # accept all Critical and Security bulletins.
    $Installer.ForceQuiet = $true
    $Installer.Updates    = $UpdateCollection
    $InstallationResult   = $Installer.Install()

    $ResultCode = $InstallationResult.ResultCode

    # test if the computer needs rebooting
    if ($InstallationResult.RebootRequired) {
        Write-Host 'Reboot required! please reboot now..' -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    else {
        Write-Host 'Done..' -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}

# Clean-up COM objects
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($UpdateSession)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($UpdateSearcher)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($UpdateCollection)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($SearchResult)
if ($Downloader) { $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Downloader)}
if ($Installer)  { $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Installer)}
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Theo@ ,let me test it. Can we use this script for all model laptops and if audio is not installed then can we change in code to install driver?

Comment: @PGT the code specifically tries to find drivers for Realtek devices (not necessarily only audio). If other laptops have devices from different manufacturers, you need to check for those there too. Give it a test first and if needed I can update to add other manufacturers in there.

Comment: I tested @Theo but it's not working as i expected , I only need audio driver to be installed for every models either update or if driver is missing. Is there any way to hide  other updates and install only audio.

Comment: @PGT I have added test for audio drivers only and clean-up code for COM objects. Hopefully this does what you expect.

Comment: @THEOI will test with different models with older version audio and let you know.

Comment: Theo@ tested with three models it's always saying no updates available even driver is older version and it gives exception sometimes as below:                         Exception from HRESULT: 0x8024401C
At C:\Users\username\Documents\updatednew.ps1:10 char:1
+ $SearchResult   = $UpdateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Dri ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
 
No Driver-Updates available...
0

Comment: Exception calling "ReleaseComObject" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At C:\Users\username\Documents\updatednew.ps1:66 char:1
+ $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($S ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException

Comment: @PGT Are you running this as Administrator? Are you sure the Windows Update service is running? Does the machine have access to internet?

Comment: Theo@ Yes i am running as administrator and windows update service is running, internet is accessible.Could you please try this yourself if possible ?

Comment: @PGT I tested on a desktop machine with Windows 10 Pro (2004) and a HP laptop with Windows 10 Pro (1909) and the code just runs fine. No COM errors. I've tested with PowerShell version 5.1. Both these machines do not have Realtek audio systems, but for test I changed it to accept all drivers. You could experiment to leave out `IsInstalled=0` on `$UpdateSearcher.Search()`

Comment: Theo@ script is running now without any error but it's not detecting driver update or missing driver it always shows no updates available,running it with execution policy unrestricted. Is there any prerequisites to run this code successfully or any group policy that needs to be updated ?